# Extracting raster values at points locations in R, but resulting in a lot of NA value

Tags: raster, r

I use point data with 28 points, to extract the values from 3 raster layers, but got a lot of NA value.
The code is like:

```
#read the point and change its coordination system to fit the raster layers
file<-paste("/Volumes/Distribution/point0.csv")
file
Point1<-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep=",")
sppoints<-SpatialPoints(Point1, proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=47 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
slope1<-brick("/Volumes/rasters/slope.tif")
slope1
tp<-spTransform(sppoints, crs(slope1))
tp


#Read the raster layers
files<-list.files("/Volumes/rasters", pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE)
files
predictors<-stack(files)
predictors

#Extract values
presvals<-extract(predictors, tp)
set.seed(0)
backgr<-randomPoints(predictors, 500)
absvals<-extract(predictors, backgr)
pb<-c(rep(1, nrow(presvals)), rep(0, nrow(absvals)))
sdmdata<-data.frame(cbind(pb, rbind(presvals, absvals)))
head(sdmdata)
tail(sdmdata)
```

Then I got head(sdmdata) results like:

```
  pb aspect elevation slope
1  1     NA        NA    NA
2  1     NA        NA    NA
3  1     NA        NA    NA
4  1     NA        NA    NA
5  1     NA        NA    NA
6  1     NA        NA    NA
```

and tail(sdmdata) results like:

```
    pb         aspect     elevation          slope
523  0 213.0868417062 3.00000000463  4.90379238129
524  0 294.1608609572 4.00000000000 10.47768211365
525  0 341.7759552833 7.00000000000 24.43413352966
526  0 246.7905575610 7.00000000000 29.83376884460
527  0 247.4420388641 3.99999999843 28.22425270081
528  0  23.7686386468 3.99999999749  4.22268724442
```

I plotted the points and raster layers in QGIS, the points fell exactly in the extent of these raster layers. I don't know why I got so many NA values.

Comment: Impossible to help you without your data here. Have you plotted the points in R to make sure they are where you think they are? Does everything have the right coordinate system?

Comment: @Spacedman Sorry that I tried uploading my data but don't know how. I plotted the point and raster in R, and yes, the point is showed with axes in degree (e.g. 97°E), and raster layer is showed with axes in maybe meter (e.g. 600000). I was thinking this might happen, so I did spTransform the point data (as shown in the code in my question). But still got NA values. I don't know how to solve this problem.Thank you for paying attention to my question.

Comment: I finally figure out why. I used UTM coordination system, which use meters as default unit, but my points are in degree. So I used QGIS to export the point in UTM coordination system, it transformed the point unit from degree to meters. I ran the code again, and it worked! Thank you :)